# Bulma Steps not proceeding to next step after clicking the submit button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, buefy, vuejs3

I am trying to create a Buefy Steps in Vue. Buefy steps are working already, but the `Submit` button does not advance to the next step (e.g., from "Account" to "Profile").

*App.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <section>
      <div class="block">
        <b-field v-if="hasNavigation" grouped group-multiline>
          <b-field label="Prev icon">
            <b-select v-model="prevIcon">
              <option value="chevron-left">Chevron</option>
              <option value="arrow-left">Arrow</option>
            </b-select>
          </b-field>
          <b-field label="Next icon">
            <b-select v-model="nextIcon">
              <option value="chevron-right">Chevron</option>
              <option value="arrow-right">Arrow</option>
            </b-select>
          </b-field>
          <b-field label="Label position">
            <b-select v-model="labelPosition">
              <option value="bottom">Bottom</option>
              <option value="right">Right</option>
              <option value="left">Left</option>
            </b-select>
          </b-field>
          <b-field label="Mobile mode">
            <b-select v-model="mobileMode">
              <option :value="null">-</option>
              <option value="minimalist">Minimalist</option>
              <option value="compact">Compact</option>
            </b-select>
          </b-field>
        </b-field>
      </div>
      <b-steps
        v-model="activeStep"
        :animated="isAnimated"
        :rounded="isRounded"
        :has-navigation="hasNavigation"
        :icon-prev="prevIcon"
        :icon-next="nextIcon"
        :label-position="labelPosition"
        :mobile-mode="mobileMode"
      >
        <b-step-item step="1" label="Account" :clickable="isStepsClickable">
          <h1 class="title has-text-centered">Account</h1>

          <form ref="loginForm" class="form-horizontal form-material" @submit.stop.prevent>
            <input type="hidden" name="customfield" class="form-control" :value="this.id">

            <div class="field is-horizontal">
              <div class="field-label is-normal">
                <label class="label has-text-black">Name *</label>
              </div>
              <div class="field-body">
                <div class="field">
                  <div class="control">
                    <b-field>
                      <input maxlength="20" class="input h" type="text" placeholder>
                    </b-field>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-right"></div>
            <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-centered">
              <p class="control">
                <a class="button is-primary" @click.prevent="next.action">Submit</a>
              </p>
              <p class="control">
                <a class="button is-light">Cancel</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </b-step-item>

        <b-step-item
          step="2"
          label="Profile"
          :clickable="isStepsClickable"
          :type="{'is-success': isProfileSuccess}"
        >
          <h1 class="title has-text-centered">Profile</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </b-step-item>

        <b-step-item step="3" :visible="showSocial" label="Social" :clickable="isStepsClickable">
          <h1 class="title has-text-centered">Social</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </b-step-item>

        <b-step-item
          :step="showSocial ? '4' : '3'"
          label="Finish"
          :clickable="isStepsClickable"
          disabled
        >
          <h1 class="title has-text-centered">Finish</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </b-step-item>

        <!-- <template v-if="customNavigation" slot="navigation" slot-scope="{previous, next}">
          <b-button
            outlined
            type="is-danger"
            icon-pack="fas"
            icon-left="backward"
            :disabled="previous.disabled"
            @click.prevent="previous.action"
          >Previous</b-button>
          <b-button
            outlined
            type="is-success"
            icon-pack="fas"
            icon-right="forward"
            :disabled="next.disabled"
            @click.prevent="next.action"
          >Next</b-button>
        </template>-->
      </b-steps>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App"
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-gagarin-ut5so)

Comment: From console TypeError: _vm.next.action is not a function. Which is because of line 67 <a class="button is-primary" @click.prevent="next.action">Submit</a>. You don't have a function to accomplish that job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you moved the contents of `b-step`'s `navigation` slot into `b-step-item` and forgot to include the parent `template` that defines the slot scope of `next`, needed for the `Submit` button's action. Even with the `template`, that wouldn't work because `b-step-item` does not have a `navigation` slot.

The solution is to put those buttons in `b-step`'s `navigation` slot:

```html
<b-step>
  <b-step-item>...</b-step-item>
  <b-step-item>...</b-step-item>
  <b-step-item>...</b-step-item>

  <template slot="navigation" slot-scope="{previous, next}">
    <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-centered">
      <p class="control">
        <a class="button is-primary" @click.prevent="next.action">Submit</a>
      </p>
      <p class="control">
        <a class="button is-light">Cancel</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </template>
</b-step>
```

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-heisenberg-z6z0l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)